How do I change the BigBlueButton Favicon on a Greenlight v3 build?
So we have a standard BigBlueButton/GreenlightDocker container.
https://github.com/bigbluebutton/greenlight/tree/master
And I'm customising the title, description, logos ... for my company.
But I can't manage to change the favicon.
Replace favicon in public folder -> no effect
add favicon.nginx
    location = /favicon.ico { alias
        alias /var/favicon/favicon.ico
    }

-> no effect
and I'm not sure how to do this since the original BBB favicon.ico shouldn't even exist anymore.
